# Is there any option to connect R with NetSuite to provide analysis result on regular basis to NetSuite users?

Tags: java, r, odbc, netsuite, rodbc

Actually, I have to build a bridge between R and NetSuite system, for instance like I want to fetch the data from NetSuite Storage and want to analyze in R and deliver back the report to NetSuite system on regular basis.\

All answers are pre welcomed, please help me to get out of this.

Comment: https://github.com/NetSweet/

Comment: If you can tolerate a paid solution, we offer [ODBC](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/netsuite/odbc/) and [JDBC](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/netsuite/jdbc/) drivers which are natively supported in R, using the RODBC and RJDBC packages, respectively. If this is acceptable to you, I can post a short walk-through for connecting to NetSuite data in R.

Comment: Thanks for your reply first, yeah it's completely fine.....

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, there are lots of options for pushing data in to and getting data out of NetSuite:

- CSV Import/Export (for a manual process)
- SOAP Web Services (SuiteTalk)
- RESTlets (SuiteScript, typically JSON)

Without more details on exactly what you are looking to do, it's hard to give further suggestions.

As an aside, this sounds like a very interesting project.

Comment: Thanks for your comment eric, actually what I have to do is, first I have to get the data from netsuite to r , do the analysis and the result should get deliver back from R to netsuite

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a strictly Netsuite answer, but with the 3rd party BI Software application Sisense, you can export your data from NetSuite (via CSV if you like, or schedule it via ODBC if you have that connection), and then use R (which is built into Sisense) to perform statistical analysis. Sisense isn't cheap of course but I've been using it for about half a year and I would recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Alex, yeah thats good but as I said I have to deliver analysis results  back to netsuite......so is it possible in anyway as regular exercise ?